# firebaserecycleradapter sort/compare/reorder data before populate

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

In my firebase database I have a collection of lat and long for each uid.

[image: Here is how it looks]

I use firebase recyler adapter data to list down my data to the recycler view.

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(Model.class, R.layout.row, ViewHolder.class, mRef) {

                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final Model model, int position) {

                    Double dist = distance(
                            myPosition.latitude,
                            myPosition.longitude,
                            Double.parseDouble(model.getLat()),
                            Double.parseDouble(model.getLon()));
                    Log.d("gs_distance", String.valueOf(dist));

                    viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(),
                            model.getLat(),
                            model.getLon(),
                            model.getGsname());
                }
```

The problem is I want to reorder/sort the data by nearest to farthest from my location, i can already fetch distance on how far each latlng is from my location. I dont know if there is a way to compare each latlng by their distance just before the data enters the populateViewHolder. Or maybe sort it after being inserted in the recyclerview? I really dont know.

```
static double distance(double fromLat, double fromLon, double toLat, double toLon) {
    Location loc1 = new Location("");
    loc1.setLatitude(fromLat);
    loc1.setLongitude(fromLon);

    Location loc2 = new Location("");
    loc2.setLatitude(toLat);
    loc2.setLongitude(toLon);

    float distanceInMeters = loc1.distanceTo(loc2);
    return distanceInMeters / 1000; //convert to km
}
```

Comment: Firebase adapters from FirebaseUI will show the data in the order in which it is retrieved from he database. I don't think it has support for reordering the items client-side. That means you'll have to write a custom adapter for it, which reads the items from the database, and orders them by distance, and then shows them in that order.

Comment: better use your own adapter, because it will give you more freedom in so many aspects

Comment: Does custom adapter only works with array lists? Im really new at this. Thanks for the reply btw, it gives me motivation to continue with my problem.

Comment: Should I use dataSnapshot to loop through my firebase data and add each into an arrayList, then from array list into the custom adapter?